# Ubuntu on mac: No display after crash

Tags: boot, drivers, gnome, macbook-pro, display-manager

I've been using the 2019 mac pro running Ubuntu for about 6 month with no problems what so ever (I know this sounds unbelievable but i really did). Crashed a maybe 3 times in total, but this 4th time it didn't just boot up like normal afterwards...
It still boots and is usable on tty2 etc. but i can't start the display manager any more ([enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/negeT.jpg)) :(
Help would greatly be appreciated! :) 
Beni

Comment: Your GDM is broken would not recommend it try to fix it do a fresh install if possible, there is no "problem" in your hardware.

Comment: Post the output of `cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log`